# Error while compiling module for linux kernel

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, kernel-module

I am using Fedora 16.The kernel is 3.3.2.-6.fc16.i686.PAE.I have installed the correct kernel devel.But when I am trying to compile any module against it I am getting an error mentioned below

> No rule to make target
>   `/usr/src/kernels/3.3.2-6.fc16.i686.PAE/arch/x86/syscalls/syscall_32.tbl',
>   needed by`arch/x86/syscalls/../include/generated/asm/unistd_32.h'. 
>   Stop.

Any idea what is wrong and what needs to be done?

Comment: Check if build dependecies are met. See: http://kdpeter.blogspot.com.br/2011/05/steps-to-test-kernel-build-on-fedora-15.html

Check the Makefile for the module. It may be pointing to wrong source path.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the kernel sources, just compile it again and try compiling your module.